# How can you generate a blockdiagram similar to this?

Tags: diagrams

I made a quick sketchup of what I want:

[image]

What would be a good way to generate a blockdiagram like this?

Comment: adapting one of those: http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/tag/diagrams/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can be done very easily with TikZ and the `matrix` library.

Even though the PGF/TikZ manual as well as [How to insert a linebreak in a TikZ matrix node?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/112724/16595) say that it is possible to use a `\\` linebreak inside a `matrix of nodes` as long it is enclosed in `{ }` it did not work for me, instead I used a simple `\node` (with the `\twoRows` macro). Any options and settings are inherited by this manual node, too.

`\foreach` loops help to connect the nodes of the matrix without repeating the same code for many rows and/or columns.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,convert=false]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\newcommand*{\twoRows}[2]{\node {$#1$\\$\scriptstyle #2$};}
\tikzset{
  -|/.style={to path={-| (\tikztotarget) \tikztonodes}},
  |-/.style={to path={|- (\tikztotarget) \tikztonodes}},
  % auxiliary styles
  set row cells to/.style n args={3}{% #1 = row, #2 = columns, #3 = style
    @set row cells to/.style={row #1 column ##1/.append style={nodes={#3}}},
    @set row cells to/.list={#2}
  },
  set rows to/.style 2 args={% #1 = rows, #2 = style
    @set rows to/.style={row ##1/.append style={#2}},
    @set rows to/.list={#1}
  }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  >=latex,
  shorten >=2\pgflinewidth,
  thick,
  rect/.style={
    shape=rectangle,
    draw,
    minimum width=5em,
    align=center,
  },
  sqplus/.style={
    shape=circle,
    draw,
    minimum size=1.5em,
    inner sep=+0pt,
    path picture={% the plus
      \draw[shorten >=+0pt]
            (path picture bounding box.west) -- (path picture bounding box.east)
            (path picture bounding box.north) -- (path picture bounding box.south);
    }
  }
]
\matrix[
  column sep=.5cm,
  row sep=.5cm,
  every node/.append style={anchor=center,text depth=+2pt},
  column 1/.style={nodes=rect},
  set row cells to={1}{2,...,5}{sqplus},
  set row cells to={4}{2,...,5,7}{sqplus},
  set rows to={2,3,5,6,7}{nodes=rect},
  row 4 column 6/.style={nodes=rect},
  row 6 column 5/.style={nodes=sqplus},
  matrix of nodes,
  ] (m) {
    0000\ldots 0 & {}    & {}    &[1cm] {} & {}                                \\
                 & \twoRows{E_{k,N}}{1000\ldots0} 
                         & \twoRows{E_{k,N}}{1000\ldots1}
                                 & \twoRows{E_{k,N}}{1000\ldots a-1} 
                                             & \twoRows{E_{k,N}}{1000\ldots a}   \\
                 & $A_1$ & $A_2$ & $A_{a-1}$ & $A_a$                             \\
    0000\ldots 0 & {}    & {}    & {}        & {}    & \twoRows{E_{k,N}}{m} & {} \\
                 & $M_1$ & $M_2$ & $M_{m-1}$ & $M_m$                             \\
                 & \twoRows{E_{k,N}}{0} 
                         & \twoRows{E_{k,N}}{1}
                                 & \twoRows{E_{k,N}}{m-2}
                                             & {}    & \twoRows{E_{k,N}}{m}      \\
                 & $C_1$ & $C_2$ & $C_{m-1}$ & $C_m$ &                      & $T$\\
  };

  \foreach \Row in {2,6}
    \path (m-\Row-3) -- node {$\cdots$} (m-\Row-4);

  \foreach \Row in {1,4}
    \foreach \cellStart[evaluate={\cellEnd={int(\cellStart+1)}}] in {1,...,4}
      \path[->] (m-\Row-\cellStart) edge (m-\Row-\cellEnd);

  \foreach \Column in {2,...,5} 
    \path[->] (m-3-\Column) edge (m-2-\Column)
              (m-2-\Column) edge (m-1-\Column)
              (m-5-\Column) edge (m-4-\Column) edge (m-6-\Column)
              (m-6-\Column) edge (m-7-\Column)
              ;
  \path[->] (m-4-5) edge     (m-4-6)
            (m-4-6) edge     (m-4-7)
            (m-4-7) edge[|-] (m-6-6) edge (m-7-7)
            (m-6-6) edge     (m-6-5)
            (m-1-5) edge[-|] (m-4-7)
            ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Astonishing! Thanks a lot, +1 and accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to draw this diagram using, for instance, Libreoffice draw and then exporting it to eps or pdf? You can easily insert PDF or EPS graphics in `LaTeX`. This is more of like a practical answer, rather than a technical one.

I tell you this because a lot of time to produce a diagram like this is required, especially when you don't know `Tikz` or `Pstricks` very well.

Comment: Could you please point out how exactly you draw the the cross on the circles?