# TikZ/pgf: Why does `\newline` and `\\` not split text in node?

Tags: tikz-pgf

**The MWE:**

```
\documentclass{standalone}

%======================================
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphdrawing}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\usegdlibrary{force, layered, trees}
%======================================

\begin{document}

\tikz 
\graph [spring layout, nodes = draw]
{
    a/"dispersive\newline collision";
    b/"non-dispersive\newline  collision";

    a -> b
};

\end{document}
```

**The output:**

[image]

**The question:**

As you can see above, the `\newline` command does nothing. Trying to use `\\` instead of `\newline`, like how the pgfmanual does in some examples (see pg. 386) has the same effect. Why? What can I do in order to have the words appear on separate "lines"?

Comment: By the way, this has nothing to do with the `graphdrawing` library either. It happens as soon as you put text in nodes.

Comment: @cfr I'll change the question again to reflect that.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

By default nodes are set in a box that doesn't allow line breaks. Adding an `align`ment (e.g. `align=center`) or `text width` to the node sets it in a paragraph box instead, where line breaks can occur. For some reason `\newline` still doesn't work (no idea why), but `\\` does.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

%======================================
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphdrawing}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\usegdlibrary{force, layered, trees}
%======================================

\begin{document}

%simpler example
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node {a\\b};
\node [align=center] at (1,0) {a\\b};
\end{tikzpicture}

% your code, modified
\tikz 
\graph [spring layout, nodes = {draw,align=center}]
{
    a/"dispersive\\ collision";
    b/"non-dispersive\\  collision";

    a -> b
};

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In my case `\\` makes new line but also puts a line in-between. @Torbjørn T.

Comment: @Alper What do you mean by "line in-between"?

Comment: My code: https://gist.github.com/avatar-lavventura/10cf7a28565c881f4c8a03b9d0d76d87 . Instead of putting new-line, text inside the node, it starts drawing new node on the next line. @Torbjørn T.

Comment: @Alper Of course, think about the context. In a `matrix` a ```\\``` means "start a new row". See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112724, you need to wrap the cell content in `{  }`, and also specify the `text width` , and finally, it doesn't seem to work with `math` nodes, try `matrix of nodes`.

Comment: You are right, I confused the terms. `\shortstack{value1\\ value}` solved my problem.