# TikZ: How to draw a flow chart using library chains and matrix of nodes?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-matrix, tikz-chains

In this MWE of a flowchart, it doesn't compile when `\chainin` command is used and I need to understand the following:

1. `align=center` doesn't center the content of the node, for example, `(m-2-1)`.
2. How can I break the line inside any of the matrix nodes since using `\\` makes the compilation run for a long time?
3. How can I join between `(m-3-1)` and `(m-1-2)` in such a way that the join goes to the right until the midway, then vertically to the left of `(m-1-2)` then right?
4. When using `\chainin` command, I got an error: **`Undefined control sequence. \chainin`** despite loading `chains` library.

I already drew this flowchart without `chains`, but I need to know if it is possible with it or not.

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,chains, positioning,matrix,shapes}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
every node/.style={draw,rectangle,align=center},
every join/.style=latex,
join
]
\matrix (m) [matrix of nodes,column sep=5mm,row sep=5mm]{
    {1\\new line}   & 4\\
    2               & 5\\
    3               & 6\\
};

{ [start chain]
    \chainin (m-1-1);
    \chainin (m-2-1);
    \chainin (m-3-1);
    \chainin (m-1-2);
    \chainin (m-2-2);
    \chainin (m-3-2);
}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't work at all here, don't you get any errors when you try? Concerning 2, seems you also need to specify `text width` for matrix nodes, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/112726/586

Comment: @TorbjørnT. My code doesn't work when using `\chainin` command as I said in my question body, and I need to understand why it fails.

Comment: Right, sorry, but you first get an error because of the line break in the first node of the matrix, which is fixed with `text width`, and then the text is centered in the nodes.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. You are right, specifying `text width` fixed my first two issues.

Comment: And the second I suppose? (I mean, `\\ ` didn't work at all without `text width`.) Anyways, I'm no `chains` expert, but I think perhaps there has to be something on the chain already for `\chainin` to work. Someone else will probably be able to answer though.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Yes, first two issues were solved; I edited my comment `:)`. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with the `Undefined control sequence` is that you're missing one library:

```
\usetikzlibrary{scopes}
```

As far as I'm aware of, It's not mentioned in the manual but I've seen this issue before.

As for your issue (3), I think it's best that you draw that line separately and break the chain into two. At least because I don't know how to modify the `\chainin` path operator...

[image]

### MWE:

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,chains,scopes,positioning,matrix,shapes,calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
every node/.style={draw,rectangle,align=center}, >=latex
]

\matrix (m) [matrix of nodes,column sep=5mm,row sep=5mm]
{
\node(m-1-1){1\\new line};  & 4\\
2               & 5\\
3               & 6\\
};

%\matrix[below=5cm] (m) [matrix of nodes,column sep=5mm,row sep=5mm]{
%   |[text width=1.5cm]| {1\\new line}  & 4\\
%   2               & 5\\
%   3               & 6\\
%};

{ [start chain,every on chain/.style={join=by ->}]
\chainin (m-1-1);
\chainin (m-2-1);
\chainin (m-3-1);
\chainin (m-1-2);
\chainin (m-2-2);
\chainin (m-3-2);
}

\draw[red,->] (m-3-1) -| ($(m-3-1)!.7!(m-1-2)$) |-(m-1-2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I also have in the MWE used a different method for making the line break inside the matrix environment (issue 2). As said so in the manual one can use nested nodes, so since every matrix cell is a node we can use a `\node` inside that node, and since we already have the style `every node` set to `align=center`, that node is already center aligned and therefore there will be no need for specifying a `text width`. Though I do not know why the key `align=center` does not work inside `\matrix`, perhaps a bug...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So, if I want to remove the black join between `(m-3-1)` and `(m-1-2)` in your answer, I have to make two chains (from 1 to 3, then from 4 to 6) instead of one single chain, right?

Comment: Yes, precisely!